# How Can to Edit the Blog Layout in Orchard Cms?

Tags: orchardcms-1.9

I want to change the blog layout.I want to order this in title then publish date,picture and then description.but I don't know how to do this.can you help me plaese?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please read up on some Orchard documentation about [placement](http://docs.orchardproject.net/en/latest/Documentation/Understanding-placement-info/), [alternates](http://docs.orchardproject.net/en/latest/Documentation/Alternates/) and [shapetracing](http://docs.orchardproject.net/en/latest/Documentation/Customizing-Orchard-using-Designer-Helper-Tools/#getting-started-with-shape-tracing).

The simplest thing you can do, for just changing the order of rendering, is changing the placement.info of your theme to something like this:

```
<Match ContentType="Blog">
    <Place Parts_Title="Content:1" />
    <Place Parts_MetaData="Content:2" />
    <Place Fields_MediaLibraryPicker="Content:3" />
    <Place Parts_Blogs_Blog_Description="Content:4" />
</Match>
```

If you want to have full control over the rendering of the layout you can create an alternate. Use the shape tracer to find the correct alternate (probably something like Content-Blog.cshtml), and tweak your stuff in there.